# Finding the sum of square of first n natural numbers

Tags: python

```
try:
    num=int(input("Enter a number:"))

    def sum(num):
        result=0
        if num < 0:
            print(num, "is not a natural number!")
        else:
            for i in range(1,num+1):
                result=result + (i*i)
            return result
    print("The sum of square of first", num, "natural number is:", sum(num))

    
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

For the given code;
How can I not execute the below statement for input less than zero?

```
print("The sum of square of first", num, "natural number is:", sum(num))
```

Putting this statement inside else block did not help!

Comment: Why are you defining the `sum()` function inside a `try/except` block?  Do you really want `sum()` to be called inside the `sum()` function itself so that it is recursive?  Since I don't see the value of `num` ever changing, I think that would produce an infinite loop.

Comment: @Steve, sorry that was a mistake.

Comment: it's also not a good idea to shadow the name `sum` which is a python builtin.

Comment: Yeah, it is good to use the builtin functions. But I am trying to increase my logical thinking, so just messing around with the code.

Comment: Note that you do not have to use a for loop to find the sum of square numbers. Take a look at this: https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can write if-else statements in one line

Eg:

`take_this if this_condition_is_True else take_this`

So now if the num is negative the `sum()` function won't even be called

```
try:
    num=int(input("Enter a number:"))

    def sum(num):
        result=0
        if num < 0:
            print(num, "is not a natural number!")
        else:
            for i in range(1,num+1):
                result=result + (i*i)
            return result
    print(f"The sum of square of first {num} natural number is: {sum(num)}" if num>=0 else "Stop giving negative numbers")

    
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

Comment: Happy to help, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `return` before the else. It should work. You can simply write `return`, or you can actually return a value depending on your necessities